# Why the answer of this Gaussian probability question is zero?

Tags: probability, gaussian, normal-distribution

Assume the average weight of an American adult male is 180 pounds with a standard deviation of 34 pounds. The distribution of weights follows a normal distribution. What is the probability that a man weighs exactly 185 pounds?

Why the answer is 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because weight is a continuous variable (a variable that can has any value within an interval). If probability is expressed as favorable cases / possible cases, there is 1 possible case (weight is exactly 185 pounds) versus infinite cases (weight is any other value, and there is infinite values within an interval)

For a Gaussian distribution, it makes more sense to ask which is the proability for a man's weight to be lower or greater than a certain value.

Comment: Is there a formula to calculate the probability for a man's weight to be lower or greater than a certain value? For example: What is the probability that a man weighs somewhere between 120 and 155 pounds?

Comment: Just use the CDF of the gaussian distribution.The value of that CDF for a certain x is the probability of the variable to have a value equal or less than x. So, if F(x) is the CDF of your gaussian distribution, the probability of someone having a weight between x1 and x2, with x2>=x1 is: F(x2)-(1-F(x1)) = F(x1)+F(x2)-1
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: BTW: I know less to nothing about probability. I just read one wikipedia article and applied some common sense (you cannot expect a variable that can have infinite values to be exactly the one you want; for that reason its probability is 0). I'm sure you can come to the right answer by yourself. If this is some sort of homework, please, don't continue here. Ask your teacher.